# django - ZeroDivisionError when using thumbnail low-level API

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I implemented thumbnails for images that are displayed in an inline form, by creating my custom form ([like this](http://blog.glaucocustodio.com/2014/04/08/display-thumbnails-in-django-admin-with-sorl-thumbnail/)).

However, in one case (that I noticed) so far, I get a ZeroDivisionError when trying to edit a project, and this is apparently caused by [this line](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py#L482) in TiffImagePlugin, which is called by get_thumbnail.

Here's the error traceback

[image]
[image]

And here's my code (note I'm also using admin-sortable but I don't think that's related):

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminFileWidget
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.forms import ModelForm
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
from models import Image

class AdminImageWidget(AdminFileWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        output = []
        if value and getattr(value, "url", None):
          t = get_thumbnail(value,'80x80')
          output.append('<img src="{}">'.format(t.url))
        output.append(super(AdminFileWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs))
        return mark_safe(u''.join(output))

class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Image
        widgets = {
          'img': AdminImageWidget,
        }

class ImageInline(SortableStackedInline):
    model = Image 
    extra = 3
    form  = ImageForm

class ProjectAdmin(NonSortableParentAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description')
    inlines = [ImageInline]
    list_filter = ('type',)
    search_fields = ('name', 'description')
```

Note this doesn't happen all the time, it only happens when trying to edit a *specific* project (and I'm assuming it might happen with others as well, but so far couldn't find more examples).

Any ideas? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Got same error, update Pillow, it helps.

```
$ pip install pillow --upgrade
```